# How to Padding between ActionBar's menu items icon When using the Support Library,

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I used the action bar support library and have to adjust Padding between ActionBar's menu items icon. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  override the style of the action bar. You can change as your requirement.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
   parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this will be working fine for 14 and higher 
i want for below api 11