# How to change margin or padding of menu items?

Tags: android

Noob question. I'm using Toolbar and menu in Android app. How i can to change margin or padding between two menu items?

All answers i found is about Sharlock bar ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678467/how-to-add-padding-between-menu-items-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131814/how-to-padding-between-actionbars-menu-items-icon-when-using-the-support-librar)) or old Action bar ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131814/how-to-padding-between-actionbars-menu-items-icon-when-using-the-support-librare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131814/how-to-padding-between-actionbars-menu-items-icon-when-using-the-support-librar)).

I think the answer near with style files, but i realy stack what parent or item name i need for my case.

My sample menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_contents"
    android:title="@string/menu_contents"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_list_numbered"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to programmatically assign an [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ActionProvider.html) using [setActionProvider()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setActionProvider%28android.view.MenuItem,%20android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider%29) on the MenuItem that gets created for the items you want to change.

Comment: Sorry, but could you give example how to set padding of margin between two menu items?